# Date stamp format correction

Tags: python, pandas

I have time stamp as below (from data logger file), how to fix it using Pandas

Time
0   2022218 14:02:46

i want the time stamp as

2022-02-18 14:02:46

At present i figured out to get date from file creation data

```
data         = pd.read_csv(fp)     
fp_date      = pd.to_datetime(os.path.getctime(fp), unit='s') # get file creation time
d1           = data.Time.str.split(" ",expand=True)
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(fp_date.date())+ pd.to_timedelta(d1[1])
```

any alternate tip let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: How would be the timestamp for a single digit day in the same month? Can you provide other examples to see what is fixed or not?

Comment: what's your expected time stamp for 2022123 14:00:00? 2022-01-23 14:00:00, or 2022-12-03 14:00:00?